# XCode 5 - Make image tappable like a button

Tags: ios, xcode, image, tap

In XCode 5, how could I have it so that when I tap a UIImage something will happen. Like a button but I dont want to use a button. I need it to be an image. I am making a game and I couldn't find how to do this anywhere else so please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need it to be an instance of UIImage because you want it to be an image button, or because you specifically do not want to use an instance of UIButton?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a loose image, so the image must be inside *something* that displays it. Make sure that that something (it might be an image view) has its user interaction enabled. Then attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to it.

Comment: User interaction enabled: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled

Comment: Tap gesture recognizer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitapgesturerecognizer_class/index.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to display your `UIImage`, it needs to be attached to a `UIView` or `CALayer`. You could do this:

```
UIImageView *notAButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[notAButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[notAButton addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedButton:)]];
[self.view addSubview notAButton];
```

What do you have against `UIButton`, by the way? It is by far the easiest and most widely-accepted way to do this.

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:aButton];
```

Comment: Is there a way to set an image onto a button in Xcode itself?